# snmp4j Unknown security name

Tags: java

I have a problem about snmp4j. The exception is about Unknown security name.
I use the snmp4j to monitoring devices and I run it in multi-thread.My code is below. Who can tell me how to fix this problem.

```
public static JSONObject snmpV3Check(Integer ida, String contextName, String ip, String userName, Integer authProtocol, String authPass, Integer privProtocol, String privPass, Integer level) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    int isSnmpConn = -1;
    UserTarget target = null;
    if (ida != null) {
        Integer snmpTimeOut = StrategyContainer.getStrategy(ida).getSnmpTimeOut();
        Integer snmpRetryCount = StrategyContainer.getStrategy(ida).getSnmpRetryCount();
        target = creatV3Default(ip, userName, level, snmpTimeOut, snmpRetryCount);
    } else {
        target = creatV3Default(ip, userName, level, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_RETRY);
    }
    ScopedPDU request = new ScopedPDU();
    request.setType(PDU.GET);
    request.setContextName(new OctetString(contextName));
    Snmp snmp = null;
    TransportMapping<?> transport = null;
    try {
        transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        snmp = new Snmp(transport);
        USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols(), new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID()), 0);
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);
        //USM usm = USMFactory.getInstance();
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);
        transport.listen();
        snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString(userName), UsmUserUtil.creatUsmUser(userName, authProtocol, authPass, privProtocol, privPass));
        ResponseEvent respEvt = snmp.send(request, target);
        if (respEvt != null && respEvt.getResponse() != null) {
            if (respEvt.getResponse().getType() == PDU.RESPONSE && respEvt.getResponse().getErrorStatus() == PDU.noError) {
                isSnmpConn = 1;
            } else {
                logger.error(">>>>>>>>>snmp(v3) Error Code About Response:{ip:{}, type:{}, ErrorStatus:{}}<<<<<<<<<", ip, respEvt.getResponse().getType(), respEvt.getResponse().getErrorStatus());
            }
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("V3snmp's Exception:’", e);

    } 

    json.put("conn", isSnmpConn);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.  Please also translate those Chinese error messages for us.

Answer (score 0):

Using the snmp v3 you must provide a security name by a design specification.
The security name should be specified through a setter of UserTarget or provided directly by a [constructor](https://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/UserTarget.html#UserTarget-org.snmp4j.smi.Address-org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString-byte:A-).
Example:

```
UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
target.setSecurityName(userName);
```

How to add a security name in the snmp v3 with details look at:

- https://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html
- https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/snmp4j/snmpv3-set-example-using-snmp4j/

Comment: I finish this problem. I uesed synchronized method.Thank you for your help.